# Gradle not properly resolving versions when downloading an artifact

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to pull down a dependency from my local artifactory instance.  The dependency is another project (org.myproject) that i own and has several spring boot dependencies.

Here is the gradle failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.myproject.xxx:yyy:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
    Required by:
      :localproject:unspecified
     > Could not resolve org.myproject.xxx:yyy:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
       > Could not parse POM http://10.x.x.x:8081/artifactory/path/to/artifact.pom
         > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar'
```

When i run gradlew dependencies it fails when it tries to determine the all the project's dependencies and their associated versions.

Searching around a bit I see and other people have complained about this in the past but their associated bugs seemed to have been resolved.  I have tried the latest gradle versions 2.3 / 2.4 and it is still not working.

The pom generated by the artifactory plugin for org.myproject which is uploaded does not have any versions explicitly associated with the spring-boot dependencies

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening here?

EDIT - ADDING MY build.gradle for org.myproject

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"    
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.170'
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "3.1.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

group = 'org.myproject.xxx'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
def publishRepoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'

war {
    baseName = "vsis-core"
    version = "${version}"
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:file:target/defaultDB'
    user = 'sa'
}

dependencies {
    def jaxenVersion = '1.1.6'
    compile "jaxen:jaxen:${jaxenVersion}"
    def apacheCommonsMath3 = '3.4.1'
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-math3:${apacheCommonsMath3}"
    compile "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.2.RELEASE"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"    
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"

    // dao libs
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache")
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    def springSecurityVersion = '4.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:${springSecurityVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springSecurityVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springSecurityVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:${springSecurityVersion}"

    compile 'org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'

    providedRuntime 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.3.1'
    testCompile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
         downloadSources = true
         downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        main(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
        }
    }
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${publishRepoKey}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications 'main'
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

Comment: Try to download `http://10.x.x.x:8081/artifactory/path/to/artifact.pom` from your browser. Will it download? What's in it? Is it a valid pom file?

Comment: Yes it is valid.  I have downloaded it and inspected it.  I just re-reviewed the gradle dependencies output and it didn't actually resolve all the dependencies in the pom.  So could it be a problem with how the artifactory plugin assembles the pom from my gradle dependencies?

Comment: Do you have a resolutionStrategy defined? If so, try removing it and seeing if you have a configuration issue. You can also refresh the cache and watch the debug log for any hints.

Comment: No resolutionStrategy, it is all pretty vanilla.  I just edited my post to add the build.gradle for the project that is uploaded to artifactory.  I removed some of the dependencies but that is pretty much it

Comment: It looks like the pom doesn't list the version for spring-boot dependencies. Please check that.

Comment: So this appears to work when I explicitly set a version on the spring-boot dependencies - e.g. compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:1.2.4.RELEASE" instead of compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop" To me this would appear to be an artifactory bug with their upload plugin. Can anyone confirm this is the case so I can file a bug? Could it be a gradle bug?